# How to enumerate installed video adapters in system

Tags: .net, opengl, video, wmi, gdi

my task is to render some video content to a selected video card with tv-out capability, so the first question is how to enumerate installed video cards, detect if it have tv-out, determine opengl driver capabilities? The second is how to setup opengl context with selected video adapter for rendering?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is only an attempt at the first part of your question but it may put you on the right track.  The WMI Code creator can generate code to query system information.  Here is the download link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8572.  And here is an example enumerating the video cards for CurrentBitsPerPixel.

[image]